# select first matching column

Tags: sql

I have data in multiple columns

```
col_a        | col_b            | col_c
-----------------------------------------------
good car     | medium sandwitch | good computer
bad computer | good wall        | bad wall
```

and I want to select the first value that starts with "`good`" from these three columns

```
result
---------
good car
good wall
```

Comment: And if there's no 'good' in any of the columns?

Comment: @jarlh then I don't want that row, but a default value or NULL would also be good.

Comment: Use a case expression.

Comment: might can use regex if in mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a simple `case` expression:

```
select case
    when col_a like 'good%' then col_a
    when col_b like 'good%' then col_b
    when col_c like 'good%' then col_c
end result
from table
```

This will evaluate in order, so order the columns in the case statement in whatever order you wish to check.

## --EDIT--

To remove the rows with no results, we have a few options:

Move this into a subquery (or CTE) with a `where` clause

```
select *
from
(
    select case
        when col_a like 'good%' then col_a
        when col_b like 'good%' then col_b
        when col_c like 'good%' then col_c
    end result
    from table
) a
where a.result is not null
```

Check all of them in your `where` clause

```
select case
    when col_a like 'good%' then col_a
    when col_b like 'good%' then col_b
    when col_c like 'good%' then col_c
end result
from table
where col_a like 'good%'
    or col_b like 'good%'
    or col_c like 'good%'
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but my issue was I had a string, like this: `then 'col_a'`